# How do you index a list in a txt file and call on the indexed values?

Tags: python, wing-ide

I am attempting to index my list, and then call on the last two values in each list separately.
For example

```
['Ashe', '1853282.679', '1673876.66', '1 ', '2 \n']
['Alleghany', '1963178.059', '1695301.229', '0 ', '1 \n']
['Surry', '2092564.258', '1666785.835', '5 ', '6 \n']`
```

I want my code to return
(1, 2) #from the first list
(0, 1) #from the second list
(5, 6) #from the third list

my code so far includes:

```
def calculateZscore(inFileName, outFileName):
    inputFile = open(inFileName, "r")
    txtfile = open(outFileName, 'w')

    for line in inputFile:
        newList = (line.split(','))

    print newList

    inputFile.close()
    txtfile.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

(I have been making attempts at indexing but the fact that there is a string in my list has been making it difficult)

Comment: i receive an error message about invalid literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don’t put quotes around your program code.  Second, here are some quick pointers:

```
def calculateZscore(inFileName, outFileName):
    # use with to open files to avoid having to `close` files
    # explicitly
    # inputFile = open(inFileName,"r")  
    # txtfile = open(outFileName, 'w')

    with open(inFileName, 'r') as inputFile, open(outFileName, 'w') as txtFile:
        for line in inputFile:
            newList = line.strip().split(',')
            last_two = newList[-2:] # this gets the last two items in the list  
            print last_two 



# indentation matters in python, make sure this line is indented all the way to the left, otherwise python will think it is part of 
# a different function and not the main block of running code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

As an aside, it looks like you are reading CSV file.  python has built-in CSV processing that you may want to consider:

```
def calculateZscore(inFileName, outFileName):
    import csv
    with open(inFileName, 'r') as inputFile, open(outFileName, 'w') as txtFile:
        reader = csv.reader(inputFile)
        for newList in reader:
            last_two = newList[-2:] # this gets the last two items in the list  
            print last_two
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That definitely works. You are correct it is a csv file but i was told to treat it as a txt file (idk why). I was unaware that you could preform .split() & .strip() at the same time. Also I'm guessing [-2:] preserves the last two characters in the list? That's super helpful to know for the future.

Comment: It preserves the last two elements in the list.  So `['apple', 'banana', 'cookie', 'donut'][-2:] == [ 'cookie', 'donut']`,

Comment: I have a side question.....Is there a way to call the last two value without deleting/removing the rest of the list?.....or is that what I am already doing?

Comment: @A_Worthy you are already doing it if you use the answer. The "old" list is newList which contains all elements in a line and the "new" list containing only the last two elements is last_two.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
newList = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')[-2:]
```

but this line should be intended with respect to the for loop, not as you show in your code example.